# Help understanding the velocity of polar curves.

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I have been studying for the AP BC Calculus exam (see this [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272628/how-know-which-direction-a-particle-is-moving-on-a-polar-curve)) and most of the questions that deal with the first derivative in polar coordinates say that if ${dr\over d\theta}<0$ and $r>0$, then the graph (in polar coordinates) is moving closer to the origin.

What about $r = 4-\theta$, which has $\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}\theta} = -1$?

Here is the graph:

[image: wolfram alpha]

Does this disprove the statement?

Comment: It does not, since $r$ is not positive in this case.

Comment: @anonymous how do I get wolfram alpha to graph the function for when the absolute value of theta is less than 4?

Comment: Sorry, I'm no expert on working with Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the derivative is negative, that means $r$ is decreasing. While $r$ is positive, that does mean that the graph is approaching the origin, but when $r$ is negative, it will continue to decrease, making the distance from the origin increase.

Comment: Ok, I am getting the issue, how can I break the graph up in the problem to show when abs(4-theta) >0

Comment: @MaoYiyi well $|4-\theta|\ge 0$ always... I'm not quite sure what you're asking. In the graph, $r$ is positive from $\theta\in [0,4)$, and is negative when $\theta\in(4,3\pi]$. In the graph above, you can find that when $\theta=4$, it hits the origin.

Comment: I am trying to get wolfram alpha just to show the positive and negative sections in two different graphs, but I just get solutions to the equations.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r+%3D+4-theta%2C+from+0+to+4 and
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r+%3D+4-theta%2C+from+4+to+3pi

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The solid portion (of each) is when $\theta>0$ while the dashed is $\theta<0$.

So, you can see that the example you gave indeed has the property that when $r>0$ and ${dr\over d\theta}<0$, that the polar plot is tending toward the origin.

Comment: how did you make the dash part?

Comment: @MaoYiyi: In *Mathematica*. I plotted $r=4-\theta$ for $0<\theta<4$ (solid), then again for $4<\theta<3\pi$ (dashed) and laid the two plots on top of one another.